# Dropdown menu of bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a component of bootstrap : the dropdown. I made my code with the help of the documentation.

This is my entire navbar :

```
<nav class="nav navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header ">                    
             <a href="Index_connect.php" class="navbar-brand ">AMG</a>                  
    </div>              


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="Index_connect.php">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </a></li>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>

    <div>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <li><p class="navbar-text"><span class="essaiActuel"></span></p></li>
            <li><a><div class="session"></div></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the 3 links I added :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The link is displayed but the dropdown menu doesn't appear. I tried to do my code in a jsfiddle and it works so I think there is a problem with the links.

**EDIT :**

I changed the links :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the jsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10895/

Comment: You don't need the first link. `bootstrap.min.js` is not a "stylesheet"

Comment: @boszlo I deleted it but it doesn't work yet :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

This is not necessary as it's a JS file.. But as I can see you are adding:

**Updated** with jQuery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Once it's version 3.0.0 and the JS File is 3.3.5. 
Try it again with both files from the same framework version

If it's working in the JSFiddle, maybe you have some extra code that is bad. So for example a div with the same ID or Class..

Also Try to show us your working JSFiddle.

Comment: I changed the links in my code, I edited my post to show what I add. Now, it's the same version. But it doesn't work anymore :/ And I add the jsfiddle in my edit

Comment: Try with these: 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Running example here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h

Comment: I tried to start from zero and create a page only for that test, but always the same error. So it's not the extra code which is wrong. I don't understand the problem :/

Comment: Look: http://jsfiddle.net/L16hvsjb/2/ It does work. Jus add external resources to "external resources" on the left (and not to CSS). AND you are not including jQuery. "Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included" . Try adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` ABOVE `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`